# Is it possible to install bcrypt manually

Tags: bcrypt

My webhost, iPage, has not yet made bcrypt available for cgi scripts, and because it's not my server I can't install bcrypt myself using pip or easyinstall etc.  My question is, would it be possible to download the bcrypt tarball to my pc and unzip and load the directories and files to my iPage site tree myself?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bcrypt is just a standard that can be implemented in different ways.

I'm not familiar with "iPage" but it sounds like you only have file access.

All you need to do is find a library that implements bcrypt in whatever cgi scripting language you are using, and then include and use it in your code.

For example if you are using php, you will look for a php library that offers bcrypt. You might find [this library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) which implements bcrypt in php. All you need to do is add the `password.php` under the lib directory to your site, then in your php scripts that need bcrypt simply `require` the new file and you should be able to use its functions. See the library documentation for information on that.

Comment: Iain, you proved to be correct - in my case it was a python library.  I downloaded and installed it to my pc then ftp'd the file ito its own subdirectory of my site's cgi-bin directory and included the python blank __init__.py file which allows the directory to become an available package for calling from other directories.  Thank you!

Comment: Wonderful news! Glad I could help you out. Perhaps you would like to mark this answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the solution?